# How to use 'hrtimer's' functions?

Tags: linux, timer

I try to call functions and use types of 'hrtimer' and 'ktime' but I got error messages like:

```
unknown type name ‘ktime_t’
HRTIMER_MODE_ABS undeclared
```

when i include the header file, for example, for linux/ktime.h I got:

```
linux/ktime.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

is there is any flag to add to the makefile? for now i use -lrt.

Comment: Is that kernel code or user space code?

Comment: Sorry, how can I known that? what is it kernel code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbols like `ktime_t` and `HRTIMER_MODE_ABS` are used *inside* the kernel to implement hrtimers.

When you want to use hrtimers from your program, just use the normal timer functions like [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) or better [timerfd_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html).

Comment: Does is mean that timer_create() is actually using cpu timer (just like hrimer)  ? How can I know that for sure ?

Comment: It means that the kernel uses whatever timer it feels like using. See `/proc/timer_list`.